# Prove that $E \frac{|X_n - X|} { 1 + |X_n - X|} \rightarrow 0$ proves convergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory

Assume $E \frac{|X_n - X|} { 1 + |X_n - X|} \rightarrow 0$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$. How to prove that this implies convergence in probaility $X_n \rightarrow X$.

I see that $$P(|X_n - X| > \epsilon) \le E |X_n - X| / \epsilon$$ but this expectation is not limited by the one that approaches 0, so ... ?

Answer (score 4):

Let $\delta > 0$ and find $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\frac{\epsilon}{1-\epsilon} = \delta$. Then,
$$
\mathbb{P}(|X_n - X| > \delta) =  \mathbb{P}\left(|X_n - X| > \frac{\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}\right) = \mathbb{P}\left( \frac{|X_n - X|}{1 + |X_n - X|} > \epsilon \right) \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon} \mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{|X_n - X|}{1 + |X_n - X|}\right]
$$

Comment: Conversely, the estimate $E{|X_n-X|\over 1+|X_n-X|}\le\epsilon/(1+\epsilon)+P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)$ shows that if $X_n$ converges to $X$ in probability then $E{|X_n-X|\over 1+|X_n-X|}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.